# Foreach and javadoc

Tags: php, javadoc

I would like to describe a "foreach" loop with javadoc.

Maybe like this ??

```
<?php 
/**
 * @var array $rowset
 * @var \MyClass $row
 */
foreach($rowset as $row){

}
```

could you validate my syntax ?

Comment: If you're looking for type hints in your editor this looks fine to me. You could consider putting the `@var $row` inside the loop but that's pretty minor.

Comment: BTW, that notation is normally called *phpdoc*; javadoc is the original tool that inspired all the PHP equivalents and works with, well, *Java*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you only want to provide type hints to your PHP IDE rather than build HTML documentation. In that case you want [variable type annotations](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/editorguide.html#vartyp-cmnt):

```
/* @var $rowset array */
/* @var $row \MyClass */
```

Please note that it's a different feature than docblocks used by javadoc clones. Main differences are:

- Start with `/*` rather than `/**`
- Argument order is swapped
- Used in different context (`@var` docblock precedes a property definition, `@var` variable type precedes a regular variable usage)
- Aimed at IDEs rather than API documentation generators

They are supported by at least NetBeans and PhpStorm.